# Привязка доменного имени к контейнеру

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Есть кластер контейнеров поднятых при помощи docker-compose. Между контейнерами и сервером, где установлен докер есть сеть. К контейнеру с базой данных можно обратится по ip, но ip сети докера постоянно меняется при переподнятии контейнеров. Как привязать доменное имя к определенному контейнеру, чтобы можно было обращаться по нему из среды, где установлен docker?

Answer (score 1):

Если контейнеры поднимаете через docker-compose то в нем можно задать постоянные IP для контейнеров.

```html
version: '3'

services:
    test_1:
        container_name: test_1
        image: some:image
        networks:
            testing_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1

    test_2:
        container_name: test_2
        image: some:image
        networks:
            testing_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2

    test_3:
        container_name: test_3
        image: some:image
        networks:
            testing_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.3

networks:
    testing_net:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

А доменное имя я прописывал через файл /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной проблемы я использовал phensley/docker-dns, который поднимается в отдельном контейнере, который принимает сокет докера, определяет все контейнеры, которые подняты у докера, генерирует доменные имена на основе имен контейнеров, выступает в роли dns сервера.